# React-Redux. After changing state by useDispatch, components not updating by useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have **useSelectors** to check if my App component is updating. The first at the beginning of App component and the second one at App return part. By clicking on letters, currendElementId in store is updating with no problem (I checked by Redux DevTools). But **useSelectors** not updating.

I know that state should update in reducers immutable, but in **createSlice** we may use mutable code, so that's not my case. (Anyway, I have already tried to make state copy, change it and then send it, but it works same way)

There are my code:
store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import pagesReducer from "./../features/Pages/pagesSlice.js";

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        pagesInfo: pagesReducer,
    },
})
```

pageSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    currentPage: 0,
    currentElementId: null,
    pages: [ // Pages
        { // Page
            id: nanoid(),
            lines: [
                { // Line
                    id: nanoid(),
                    aligned: "left",
                    content: [
                        { // Symbol
                            id: nanoid(),
                            type: "symbol",
                            symbol: "F",
                            isBold: false,
                            isItalic: false,
                            isUnderlined: false,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: "black",
                        },
                        { // Symbol
                            id: nanoid(),
                            type: "symbol",
                            symbol: "o",
                            isBold: false,
                            isItalic: false,
                            isUnderlined: false,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: "black",
                        },
                        { // Symbol
                            id: nanoid(),
                            type: "symbol",
                            symbol: "r",
                            isBold: false,
                            isItalic: false,
                            isUnderlined: false,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: "black",
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: nanoid(),
                    aligned: "left",
                    content: [
                        { // Image
                            id: nanoid(),
                            type: "image",
                            imageSrc: "./img/me and the boys.png",
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
}

const textSlice = createSlice({
    name: "pagesInfo",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        changeCurrentElementID(state, action) {
            state.currentElementId = action.payload;
            // return {
            //     ...state,
            //     currentElementId: action.payload,
            // }
        }
    },
})

export const { changeCurrentElementID } = textSlice.actions;
export default textSlice.reducer;
```

index.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import store from "./app/store.js";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import css from "./App.module.css";
// import BoldingTextButton from "./features/BoldingTextButton/BoldingTextButton.js";
import "./nullStyle.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { changeCurrentElementID } from "./features/Pages/pagesSlice.js";
import EnterImageButton from "./features/Pages/EnterImage/EnterImageButton.js";
import TextSizing from "./features/Pages/TextSizing/TextSizing.js";
import TextDecoration from "./features/Pages/TextDecoration/TextDecoration.js";
import TextAligning from "./features/Pages/TextAligning/TextAligning.js";

function App(props) {
  console.log(useSelector(state => state.currentElementId));

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  //   const target = event.target.closest("li")

  //   if (target) {
  //     const elementID = target.getAttribute("elementid");

  //     dispatch(changeCurrentElementID(elementID));
  //   }
  // })

  const changeElementID = event => {
    const target = event.target.closest("li")

    if (target) {
      const elementID = target.getAttribute("elementid");

      dispatch(changeCurrentElementID(elementID));
    }
  }

  const GetPageContent = () => {
    const rawPageLinesContent = useSelector(state => state.pagesInfo.pages[state.pagesInfo.currentPage].lines);
    const currentElementID = useSelector(state => state.currentElementId);

    const completedPageContent = rawPageLinesContent.map(line => {
      return (
        <ul key={line.id} className={css["page-line"]}>
          {
            line.content.map(element => {
              let finalElement;

              if (element.type == "symbol") {
                const style = { fontSize: element.fontSize + "px" }

                finalElement = (
                  <li onClick={changeElementID} key={element.id} elementid={element.id} className={`${css["page-line__item"]} ${css["page-line__symbol"]}`} style={style}>{element.symbol}</li>
                )

                if (currentElementID == element.id) {
                  finalElement = (
                    <input key={element.id} elementid={element.id} maxLength="1" className={`${css["page-line__item"]} ${css["page-line__symbol"]} ${css["page-line__choosen"]}`} style={style} value={element.symbol} />
                  )
                }
              }
              else if (element.type == "image") {
                finalElement = (
                  <li onClick={changeElementID} key={element.id} elementid={element.id} className={`${css["page-line__item"]} ${css["page-line__image"]}`}>
                    <img src={element.imageSrc} width={element.width} height={element.height} alt="image" />
                  </li>
                )
              }
              // else if (element.type == "enter") {
              //   finalElement = (
              //     <li key={element.id} elementid={element.id} className={`${css["page-line__item"]} ${css["page-line__image"]}`}>
              //       <br />
              //     </li>
              //   )
              // }

              return finalElement;
            })
          }
        </ul >
      )
    })

    return completedPageContent;
  }

  return (
    <div className={css["App"]}>
      <header className={`${css['App__header']} ${css['tools']} `}>
        <EnterImageButton />
        <TextSizing />
        <TextDecoration />
        <TextAligning />
        <div>{useSelector(state => state.currentElementId) || 0}</div>
      </header >
      <div className={`${css['App__content']} ${css['pages']} `}>
        <div className={`${css['pages__item']}`} >
          {GetPageContent()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: 2 things - don't use `addEventListener` - you'll be adding it multiple times. The other thing is that you aren't actually returning the state from your reducer?

Comment: Okay, I won't use addEventListeners.
I'm not returning state, because createSlice must see changes in state. At least that wrote here: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#reducers-and-immutable-updates

Comment: Anyway, state is changing. Problem is components aren't rerendering

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I haven't used redux/toolkit and I knew it did things differently, I wasn't aware you didn't have to return the state either (hence the ?). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.

Since you have

```js
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        pagesInfo: pagesReducer,
    },
})
```

your `pages` slice is mounted as `slice.pagesInfo`.

So you need to do

```js
useSelector(state => state.pagesInfo.currentElementId)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked. I tried to fix it for 2 days already but couldn't.

Comment: I'd highly recommend installing the Redux devtools browser extension. You can look at your store that way and notice things like this.